# Why the banner image not taking up the full width and height of the viewport(it's not visible even), it should be visible behind the Navbar too

Tags: html, css, image, header, banner

Please refer to the code below-
DRIVE LINK - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wv8Va0LIF2eg7fIOuAIp1DeY7cC-9Ne0/view?usp=share_link
HTML-

```
   <section class="main">
    <div class="banner-img w-100 vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="content text-center">
            <h1>Welcome to Techno Fair</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
    <!-- Main Section End -->

</body>
</html>
```

css-

```
.nav-item {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-link {
    color:  #89d6fb !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.main {
    padding: 280px 0 220px;
}
.banner-img {
    background-image: url("media\wallpapersden.com_virtual-reality-technology_3840x2160.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried verifying the path, still the image isn't visible.
I want the image to take the full height and width of the viewport.

Comment: Please add a code snippet with full HTML/CSS. It will be easier to debug

Comment: Attached to a drive link, you can see

Comment: I am unable to see the code in the link you have given, and in any case SO asks that you include all relevant code as a snippet within your question rather than on an external site. Not only do some users not like to open unknown sites, your question and any answers will be useless for future readers should that site be removed or 'mended'. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ...and please actually verify the path of the image. What is that backslash for?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding background-image to the #header section like this:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-image: url('https://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Rainbow/Rainbow_on_Mountain_HD_Image.jpg');
}

nav.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar {
    padding: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif ;
    color: blue !important;
}

.nav-item {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-link {
    color: black !important;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    /* background: ; */
    color: turquoise;
    /* border-radius: 5px; */
    transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

.main {
    background: url("images\abstract_low_poly_communications_design_background_0107.jpg");
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 280px 0 220px;
}

.main h2{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    color: blueviolet;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main p{
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: blanchedalmond;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .contact {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Techno Fair</title>    
    <!-- CSS -->        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">    
    <!-- FONTS -->
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap');
    </style>    
    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="" alt="">Techno Fair
        </a>    
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
        aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>   
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link contact">Contact</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </nav>
   </section>  
 <!-- Header Section End -->

 <!-- Main Section start -->
   <section class="main">
     <div class="banner-img w-100 vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
       <div class="content text-center">
         <h1>Welcome to Techno Fair</h1>
       </div>
     </div>   
   </section>
 </body>
```

Comment: Bro I want image only in a particular header section, not in the whole body

Comment: Hi @user20563982 , is this what you needed? Let me know if you need more changes.